# MVI not user intention

Tags: android

What if there no intent, I mean what if I need to load data on screen without user interaction, for example on start, how can I trigger the event without intent? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I believe you should paste some parts of your code. This question is really vague.

Comment: what event do you want to trigger?